# Node-Red failed to open SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, node-red

I am trying to access an SQLite database from Node-Red. Node-Red is unable to open the DB. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.3.

My flow and SQLite node definitions are provided below. The inject and debug nodes only have default values. I am keeping it very simple since this is my first attempt at SQLite with Node-Red.

[image]
[image]

When I deploy my flow, I get the following error:

[image]

The db has read-write-execute privileges for all users. It is local on my machine and I am the only one using it.

Any idea what could be causing the issue ?

Comment: can you open it with the sqlite command line tools?

Comment: And does the user running Node-RED have access to all the elements in the path to the file?

Comment: @hardillb Yes the db can be opened with the sqlite3 command line. The user has access to all elements in the path to the file. I tried moving the file to ~/snap/node-red/common/farm_data.db, but same problem.

Comment: Anything else in the Node-RED logs (not the sidebar)?

Comment: @hardlib Nope that's all it says...

Comment: How was the file created? Was it an existing DB that you are trying to open with Node-RED?

Comment: @hardillb The file was created using the command:
$ sqlite3 farm_data.db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right here is how I solved the issue.

I was also having problems opening .csv files. By looking at other similar posts it seemed to be a user privilege problem which could not be resolved, even by changing the file privileges with `chmod`.

I had installed all the node components using different mediums:

- nodejs and npm from the command line
- node-red from the Ubuntu Software Center
- node-red-dashboard and node-red-node-sqlite from the node-red browser.

These different installation mediums might have caused privilege issues. So I uninstalled everything.

I then reinstalled everything from the command line. Node packages were installed globally (i.e. with "-g" attribute):

```
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo apt install npm
sudo npm install -g node-red
sudo npm install -g node-red-dashboard
sudo npm install -g node-red-node-sqlite
```

I then confirmed npm could see everything as global packages:

```
sudo npm list -g --depth 0
```

[image]

I now launch node-red in a shell:

```
node-red
```

Then by going to a browser and typing:

```
localhost:1880
```

the node-red browser loads, all dashboard and sqlite nodes are available and I am able to read sqlite & csv files.

*** Note regarding installing node-red sub-packages ***

Node-red sub-packages (node-red-dashboard, node-red-node-sqlite, ...) can be installed from npm or from the node-red browser.

However I noticed a few things:

- a sub-package installed from the browser will not show up when typing `npm list -g --depth 0`.
- a sub-package installed with `sudo npm -g <sub-package>` will show up with `npm list -g --depth 0`.
- packages listed in the browser will not all show up with command `npm list <package>`.

So I decided to play it safe and install all my node-red sub-packages with `npm list`. First I search for my sub-package in the node-red browser palett list, I retrieve the sub-package name, then I install it from the shell using `sudo npm -g <sub-package>`.

Consistency solved the problem: installing everything from the shell as global packages.